# Advice on Twitter like UIView

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a question on some UIView stuff. I want to create a Twitter-like UIView cf image. So, how to create this type of view? Is it composed of several UIViews like 1 for the topbar and a second for the content (white one).

- If yes, how to create this shadow between these views?
- How to create the white arrow on top left (just under the image).

Any code sample will be appreciated. Thanks all!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM8Qt.png

Answer (score 0):

It's simple UIViewController with white background, containing UITableView with one cell.